# Vectors problem, need help

Tags: vectors

> $A,B,C$ are $3$ unit vectors such that  $$|A-B|^2+|B-C|^2+|C-A|^2=9$$
>
> Show that 
>   $$0\le|2A+5B+5C|\le\sqrt{54}$$

My try

$|2A+5B+5C| \le |2A|+|5B+5C|$

$|2A+5B+5C|^2 \le 4|A|^2+25|B+C|^2 \le 4+25 (2)=54$

$|2A+5B+5C|\le\sqrt{54}$

Is that Ok , what about the other side of inequality?

Comment: What do you mean about "the other side of inequality"? The greater or equal to 0? You get that by definition of absolute value

Answer (score 2):

One can do much better than an inequality. Notice $$|A+B+C|^2 = 3(|A|^2+|B|^2+|C|^2) - (|A-B|^2+|B-C|^2+|C-A|^2) = 3(3)-9 = 0$$
We have 
$$A+B+C = 0 \quad\implies\quad |2A+5B+5C| = |5(A+B+C)-3A| = |-3A| = 3$$

By the way, what you have stated in the question isn't valid. For example, when you write
$$|2A+5B+5C|^2 \le 4|A|^2+25|B+C|^2$$

It seems you are assuming given any two vector $X, Y$, one has $|X+Y|^2 \le |X|^2 + |Y|^2$. In general, this is only valid when the angle between $X$ and $Y$ is obtuse (i.e $\ge 90^\circ$).

Comment: $|X+Y|^2\le |X|^2+|Y|^2$ is always true. Look up triangle inequality.

Comment: @Andrei triangle inequality is $|X+Y|^{\color{red}{1}} \le |X|^{\color{red}{1}}+|Y|^{\color{red}{1}}$.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry, you are right. Thanks. The squares are generalized Pythagoras's theorem